Is there a way to do DATA formatting for Google Sheets on a Galaxy Tablet?
I cannot find any user interface for Google Sheets on a Samsung Galaxy Tablet.  There are plenty of options for changing fonts, colors, etc. but formatting DATA (date formats, currency formats, etc.) does not appear to be supported.
I have searched the web, but all the hits I get ignore the Galaxy Tab input and present how to do it on a computer. Or else, if my search doesn't emphasize "DATA formatting", I get help with changing fonts.
